# OpenGL: UV values not interpolating in fragment shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, texture-mapping, texture2d

I've been trying to convert some old OpenGL code over to use shaders, and I've run into a problem getting my fragment shader to draw a texture on a cube. However, all I see is a grey cube instead. I've debugged my .obj loader code and I know that the UVs are getting loaded correctly, and I know the texture is being loaded from disk and put on the GPU correctly. After quite a lot of testing, I found out that my UV values are not being interpolated across the face of each triangle. That is, it looks like every fragment gets the uv value 0.0,0.0 (This is the first uv value in my buffer) Any ideas why?

Here is my fragment shader:

```
#version 430 core

in vec3 color;
in vec2 uv;
uniform sampler2D tex;
out vec3 frag_color;

void main()
{
    //frag_color = color;
    frag_color = texture(tex,uv).rgb;
}
```

And my vertex shader:

```
#version 430 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 pos;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 normal;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 uv;
uniform mat4 mvMatrix;
uniform mat4 mvpMatrix;
attribute vec3 lightPos;
out vec3 color;
out vec2 uv_out;

void main()
{
uv_out = uv;

vec3 modelViewVertex = vec3(mvMatrix * vec4(pos,1.0));
vec3 modelViewNormal = vec3(mvMatrix * vec4(normal,0.0));
vec3 modelViewLightPos = vec3(mvMatrix * vec4(lightPos,1.0));

vec3 lightVector = normalize(lightPos - pos);
float diffuse = clamp(dot(normal,lightVector),0,1);

gl_Position = mvpMatrix * vec4(pos,1.0);
color = vec3(diffuse,0.0,0.0);

}
```

Here is where I set up the buffers:

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexBufferObjectID);
glBindVertexArray(vertexBufferObjectID);
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size()*sizeof(vec3), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glGenBuffers(1, &normalBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normals.size()*sizeof(vec3), &normals[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glGenBuffers(1, &UVBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, UVBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvs.size()*sizeof(vec2), &uvs[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Finally, here is my render loop:

```
glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glUniform1i(textureID, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalBuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, UVBuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

mvpMatrix = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix;
glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &mvpMatrix[0][0]);
mvMatrix = viewMatrix * modelMatrix;
glUniformMatrix4fv(mvMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &mvMatrix[0][0]); 
glVertexAttrib3fv(lightposID, &lightpos[0]);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size());

glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
```

Again, everything looks correct based off what I've read. Anything look wrong?

Comment: Are you getting anything from `glGetError()`?

Comment: This should not even compile, you have some invalid whitespace in the middle of your `#version` directive, making it `# version`. You should also be using `texture (...)` instead of `texture2D (...)` (deprecated) in a core GLSL 3.30 shader.

Comment: @zero: glGetError() was returning an error when I called   
       glVertexAttrib3fv(lightposID, &lightpos[0]);

However, when I re-enabled vertex lighting, that went away. The error was that "lightposID" was not properly initialized (I guess the shader optimized it away since I wasnt using it) Other than that, nothing.

Comment: @Andon, I modified the code per your suggestions (see above) and still nothing. Not sure why it was still compiling even though I had syntax errors, I guess Nvidia's drivers are pretty permissive

Comment: Well, there is another issue: `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, surf->w, surf->h, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surf->pixels)`. Assuming this is a core profile context, it is no longer acceptable to pass the number of channels you want the image to have as the internal format to `glTexImage2D (...)`, you need to use an actual format enum (e.g. `GL_RGB8` instead of **3**). And since we are on the topic of 3 component textures, it is completely unnecessary to do this: `vec4 (texture (...).rgb, 1.0)`, because GL automatically fills in **1.0** for `.a` when you sample a 3 component texture.

Comment: @Andon Updated again, still the same issue

Comment: So I found out that the issue goes deeper than just the texture. It looks like my UV values aren't being interpolated correctly. I've revised the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to hand the `uv` varying from the vertex to the fragment shader. You can not have an `in` attribute of the same name in both the vertex and the fragment shader. Instead you must have some `in` attribute in the vertex shader, which is then passed to an `out` varying with the same name as an corresponding `in` in the fragment shader.

In your case your vertex shader already has an `out` varying `uv_out`. Hence the fragment shader varying needs to be named `uv_out` as well, i.e. in the fragment shader

```
in vec2 uv_out
```

Of course the name `uv_out` is then a bit misleading.

Comment: That worked perfectly, I can't believe I forgot that :) Thanks!